# Disable "Connect from" log in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have this options in defaults section in haproxy.cfg:

```
 option dontlog-normal
 option dontlognull
```

But still have this type of log lines in the logfile:

```
localhost haproxy[28330]: Connect from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2536 to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:80 (http-in/HTTP)
```

How can I disable this lines in the logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

specify a min log level to notice, eg:

```
log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
```